# How to use nexus 7 for devlopment with mac os

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

Im setting eclipse on MacOS 10.8 for android development. My Nexus 7 does not show up in the Android device chooser list. I have an HTC One S and that works fine.

Here are the things i have tried.

- enabled developer mode on the nexus
- installed all Android SDK extras
- tried switching between both MTP and PTP modes on nexus
- Installed Android File transfer App on Mac.

There are several versions of this question on SO, most of the answers pertain to windows machines. Note i'm interested in a MacOS solution

Comment: Does the installer app start up when you plug it in? Does the computer recognize it, just not eclipse?

Comment: the computer does not recognize it at all.

Comment: Try the general troubleshooting if you haven't already; try a different cable, computer, usb port. It could be the tablet or cable. I'm currently using a nexus 7 on a mac 10.9 and the computer detects it immediately.

Comment: yeah everyone says it should just work. I've tried different cables and different ports. And it does just work for my htc one s. Not sure why the nexus 7 which should be a developer tablet is so problematic

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem & came across this post. For me ono's comment worked. I needed to use a usb **data** cable - not a usb **charge only** cable.

See http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130418072711AA6kqOP

For me that happened to be a usb I used to transfer books to my Kindle.

Once I connected the correct usb on the upper left corner the Nexus 7 printed

> Connecting as a Camera
>
> USB Debugging Connected

I already had USB debugging enabled and in an attempt to fix this problem I had selected Camera (PTP) instead of Media device (MTP) under the Android Settings - Storage - : (Eclipse) - USB computer connection

Comment: Using the cable provided by google works for me ( my others cable doesn't work) on mac OS

Comment: After struggling with many configurations, this is the one that worked for me. Even the cable provided by Nexus didn't work; I used a WD one for the hard drive instead.

Answer (score 2):

Reset ADB by going to the DDMS perspective, look at the devices View and you will see a drop down arrow with one of the options being to "Reset ADB".  I'm using the same setup and I have to do this from time to time.

Also, adb seems to be more stable when **neither** MTP or PTP modes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging your Nexus into a USB hub attached to your Mac.

After tearing my hair out for a day, trying every single cable and set of troubleshooting steps I could find online, I found out that if I plug my Nexus 7 into a crappy little USB hub I have kicking around it works PERFECTLY. If I plug it directly into my Mac I get nothing. (Running MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 on a late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina BTW.)

Comment: Thank you very much!
The only way that seems to work for me.
But why?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this can help you but I see my Nexus 7 tablet in Google Chrome Canary on Mac Os 10.9.1 after doing that:

- Installing Chrome Canary on the Mac 
  - On the nexus 7 : in the    settings, click 7 times on the "version" to allow developer mode (not    a joke)
- In the general settings of your device, the "developer    options" items shows up, click on it and in the submenu allow USB    debugging
- Plug in the USB cable between the device and the mac 
  - On    your device in Chrome Canary: go to "webbdevelopper tools" and allow    USB debugging
- On the mac, in canary your devices will appear at    this adress :
  chrome://inspect/#devices

You can inspect the devices with the usual debugging tools (You can open URLs and inspect them) through Chrome Canary.

If I am not clear, the whole procedure is demoed in a video in the course "Web mobile development" at Udacity.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too.  It appears that Nexus 7 devices have an issue with their data pins inside the micro USB slot getting worn out.

My resolution was to

1) blow into the port and try to clean out any dust.
2) i used a small paper clip to pry the data pins up slightly (the inside pins, the 2 outer pins are for power).

This worked for me, as now the data pins in the slot are making contact with the cable pins.  Be careful though!

Comment: Yes at this point im pretty sure my data pins are defective. I tried blowing and that did not work. im not sure how to pry them up. Its just a bar not individual pins